Disable iOS Keyboard text replacement in UITextView
Is there a way to disable iOS Keyboard text replacement in UITextView via Swift code?
(Settings > General > Keyboards > Text Replacement)
Note: textView.autocorrectionType = .no doesn't affect text replacement.

We can analyse what distinct "characteristics" does a text replacement have, and check for those in the shouldChangeTextIn delegate method, and return false when we think this is a text replacement.
From what I observed, a text replacement has the following characteristics:

replacementText is not empty. Users cannot add an empty entry in the Text Replacement settings.
range is not empty.
range is not selected. This is what differentiates a text replacement from a user selecting a range of text and starts typing new text, replacing the selection.

(The same applies for autocorrect, which I assume you also want to disable too.)
Inverting the conditions, we can implement shouldChangeTextIn like this:
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    return text.isEmpty || range.length == 0 || textView.selectedRange == range
}


Thanks. However, the highlighted text and the suggestion box are still shown when using autocorrectionType = .no (https://postimg.cc/BPgHJVSH). Without it, there is only the highlighted text with suggestions in the keyboard itself.

@HassanTaleb I've only tried this on a simulator that is connected to my MacBook keyboard, so maybe that's why. I have deleted that part of the answer. This should still prevent the actual text replacement.

if
textView.autocorrectionType = .no
is not working. Then you can change the XIB/Storyboard setting. Disable the autocorrection from the XIB/Storyboard setting.enter image description here

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
